# I have java.ulti.NoSuchElementException: No line found when i try to build a terminal menu in Java

Tags: java

I'm generally new to Java. Today i tried to make a program that has terminal menu on it, when i run my code the menu run comepletely fine for the first time but when it try to run twice i get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

This is the full message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at helloworld.displayMenu.display(displayMenu.java:17)
at helloworld.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

This is my code:

```
package helloworld;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class displayMenu {
    static void display() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int userChoice = 0;
            do {
                System.out.println("\t MENU");
                System.out.println("1. Execute Part 1");
                System.out.println("2. Execute Part 2");
                System.out.println("3. Execute Part 3");
                System.out.println("4. Exit");
                System.out.print("Choose program you want to run (1-4): ");
                userChoice = 0;
                String nextIntString = scanner.nextLine(); //get the number as a single line
                userChoice = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString); //convert the string to an int
                switch(userChoice) { //start program corresponding to user input
                    case 1:
                        part1.run();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        part2.run();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        part3.run();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Exiting...");
                        break;
                    default: //prompt the user when they input wrong
                        System.out.println("Your input is wrong (1-4)");
                }
            }while(userChoice != 4);
        }
    }
}
```

How can this run for the first time but not the second time?
I had tried to use

```
    while(scanner.hasnextLine()){
        String nextIntString = scanner.nextLine();
        userChoice = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString);
    }
```

but it doesn't solve my problem

Here's also part 1-3 and main code if you need it!

Main:

```
package helloworld;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayMenu.display();
    }
}
```

Part 1:

```
package helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class part1 {
    static void run(){
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int sum = 0;
            float avg = 0;
            System.out.print("Input column: ");
            int columns = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Input row: ");
            int rows = scanner.nextInt();
            int[][] arr = new int[columns][rows];
            //Loop input x y
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    System.out.print("Input number at ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
                    arr[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
            //Calculate Sum
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    sum += arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Your matrix is:");
            //Calculate array
            avg = (float)sum / (columns*rows);
            //Display array
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            //Display sum
            System.out.println("Sum: "+ sum);
            //Display average
            System.out.printf("Average: "+ "%.2f", avg);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Part 2:

```
package helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class part2 {
    static void run() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Input number 1: ");
            float num1 = scanner.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Input number 2: ");
            float num2 = scanner.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Input the operator (+-*/): ");
            char inputChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            switch(inputChar) {
            case '+':
                System.out.println("The result is: " + (num1 + num2));
                break;
            case '-':
                System.out.println("The result is: " + (num1 - num2));
                break;
            case '*':
                System.out.println("The result is: " + (num1 * num2));
                break;
            case '/':
                System.out.println("The result is: " + (num1 / num2));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Part 3:

```
package helloworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class part3 {
    static void run() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Input number of names you want to input: ");
            int numberofStudents = scanner.nextInt();
            String [] listofStudents = new String[numberofStudents];
            for(int i = 0; i < numberofStudents; i++) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of student number "+(i+1)+": ");
                listofStudents[i] = scanner.nextLine();
                scanner.nextInt();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < numberofStudents; i++) {
                listofStudents[i] = listofStudents[i].toUpperCase();
            }
            System.out.println("The complete list of student which are converted to upper case:");
            for(int i = 0; i < numberofStudents; i++) {
                System.out.println((i+1)+"."+listofStudents[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the part# classes, you are defining a new `Scanner` based on the standard input stream. You are using try with resources, which means the `Scanner` closes after the `try` block. This in turn also closes the input stream associated with that `Scanner`. In this case that is the standard input stream, shared between all Scanners in your program. Once that input stream is closed, no `Scanner` can read from it. See this minimal example, which causes the same exception:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner1.close();

        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner2.nextLine();
    }
```

To fix this, try passing the scanner along to your run methods instead of declaring a new one, and remove the try block in those methods.